# Xcode: Why is my NSLog getting called twice?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have an ID for a post from my server that I would like to access in two different view controllers. The first view controller is a table view that displays the posts. The user will select a row and the ID for that post will be passed to the next view controller to display details about the post. I use the code below.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    PFObject *objectId = [collectionArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    selectedObjectID = [objectId objectId];
    self.objectID = [objectId objectId];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"details" sender:self];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier  isEqual: @"details"]) {
        PreviewDetailsViewController *details = (PreviewDetailsViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        details.objectID = self.objectID;
    }
}
```

"selectedObjectID" is an extern variable and "self.objectID" is a property I set for both classes and tried to set it in the prepareForSegue method. Both of these ways of doing it do the same thing. It passes the variable to the next view controller but when I

```
NSLog(@"object = %@", self.objectID);
```

or

```
NSLog(@"object = %@", selectedObjectID);
```

in the viewDidLoad of the next view controller, it passes the ID to the next view controller, but it logs out this

```
object = (null)
object = Zz81bHEeJD
```

It's like it is getting called twice and the call that matters when I try to query for "self.objectID" or "selectedObjectID" I get

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
reason: 'Cannot do a comparison query for type: (null)'
```

which is causing me much headache.

Can anyone explain to me what is going on here and how I can rectify this?

Comment: Not necessarily an answer, but more a clarification question: Did you connect the segue from the table view row or the controller? If it's from the row, then the segue is called before the didSelect method where the performSegue will get called again. I've just stumbled into this yesterday and solved it by segueing from the UITableViewController and NOT from the row and calling the performSegue from the didSelect method.

Comment: That you for your reply. Yes I did have the segue going from the view controller to view controller.

Comment: It's far off and I don't know how you construct your array, but I typically ask: self.item = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath] in didSelectRow . But like I've said - I'm probably digging in the wring spot. And, maybe it's related to that: the segue.identifier comparison should be [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"details"].

Comment: I got it working now. It's one of those things where I fiddled with it and I'm not sure what I did, but it's working now. Your solution makes sense though.

Comment: Updated my comment with:  
the segue.identifier comparison should be [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"details"]

Answer (score 1):

`viewDidLoad` gets called when your view controller is loaded.  When you are in `prepareForSegue`, you know that the view controller has already been loaded - because you are able to get a reference to it from `destinationViewController`.  This means that `viewDidLoad` executes before you assign a value to `details.objectId`.

You should access the property in a method such as `viewWillAppear`, or trigger your query in a custom setter for the `objectId` property on your `PreviewDetailsViewController`.

And I assume that the `extern` was just for testing, but don't use externs